# Webhook on Heroku hosted app not updating

Tags: go, curl, heroku, webhooks

My curl message updates a webhook on my website perfectly when I run the site locally, using 'localhost:800' as the URI, with 'ws://localhost:8080/ws' in the webpage javascript code and "curl -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "content-type: application/json" -XPOST -d '{"object":"event","data":{"paid":true}}' localhost:8080/webhook" as the curl message sent. However when I send the same curl message to the Heroku hosted site:'https://XXXX.herokuapp.com/webhook' with 'ws://XXXX.herokuapp.com/ws' on the webpage it doesn't update with the info received in the curl, though from the Heroku logs I can see that the message was received. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Does it always not work? Do you have multiple heroku dynos running, allowing the webhook to end up at one dyno while your websocket connects to another? What do the browser console logs/network say about the websocket? Heroku have a golang+websocket demonsrates how to do it. It might be worth comparing their Procfile with your own: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-websockets

Comment: Could you provide us with more information (logs, application design, [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: I've discovered that it works with http but not https. I'm using Gorilla webhooks, so need to see if there is an example using ListenAndServeTLS, instead of  ListenAndServe I think.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to change "var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://myapp.herokuapp.com/ws")" to "var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://myapp.herokuapp.com/ws")" in the .html page. Now it works fine. I have a SSL Cert in Heroku for that App and this seems to work with wss as well as https